# How do I choose both instances within the random choice function?

Tags: python

I may seem unclear but here is what I want, I would like to use both instances within a random.choice function.

So here is the code:

```
B = True
C = True
x = random.choice([B, C])
d = ?
```

I want (d) to hold the left over choice once (x) has been chosen, so let's say if (x) was (B) I would like (d) to hold (C).

Comment: You might need some more varied data in order for us to provide an answer. As is sits, B/C/D/X all have the same ID because they all point to True. b/c/d/x are just labels on True, so you are not really holding anything in your variables to make them different.

Comment: I'm making a game, at the moment they are all true but I will use if statements to change their values to false.

Comment: Note that, if you're choosing uniformly between two options -- that is, each has a 50% chance of being chosen -- selecting one at random and selecting one at random and then taking the other *are the same operation*. In each case, each of the two options still has a 50% chance of being picked. So, *if you don't need `x` but only `d`,* `random.choice()` is actually enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x, d = random.sample([B, C], 2)
```

`random.sample([B, C], 2)` will return either `[B, C]` or `[C, B]` randomly, and then we use tuple unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean [numpy.random.choice()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) there is no way to have the function return the remaining item directly.

An easy way to do it for 2 elements would be something like

```
import numpy
choices = (B, C)
i = numpy.random.choice((0, 1))
chosen = choices[i]
leftover = choices[1 - i]
```

Comment: why does numpy.random.choice((0, 1)) hold two brackets?

Comment: @Ruthless: The inner set of parenthesis indicates a [tuple](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/tuple), which in this case represents an interval.

Comment: @Ruthless because we need to pass a tuple of choices as a single argument, not two arguments 0, 1 - in fact you'll get a ValueError if you remove the second pair of brackets